# jaxb xjc -wsdl command unknown location

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I am trying to generate the schema classes from wsdl using the JAXB xjc tool and I am facing the below message:

**xjc -verbose -wsdl https://xyz/wsdl.aspx**

parsing a schema...

compiling a schema...

[INFO] generating code

**unknown location**

However, I have tried to with a different wsdl url as below:

**xjc -verbose -wsdl http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl**

parsing a schema...

compiling a schema...

[INFO] generating code

**unknown location**

com\cdyne\ws\weatherws\ArrayOfForecast.java

com\cdyne\ws\weatherws\ArrayOfWeatherDescription.java

com\cdyne\ws\weatherws\Forecast.java

etc....

**For this 'Weather' wsdl, though I have noticed that there is 'unknown location', the command could successfully generate the schema classes.**

I have tried to google and refer the below site, but could not find anything helpful on this subject.
https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html

**I did not understand clearly from xjc log (which says 'unknown location') on what is the exact issue ?**

**If it is an issue then how could it generate the schema classes for the second 'Weather' wsdl url ?**

How do I fix the issue and generate schema files for the first url (https://xyz/wsdl.aspx) ?

I tried to use 'jaxb2-maven-plugin' inside the eclipse, but did not generate any files without any errors. Is it also for the same reason ?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely complaining about the url <wsdlsoap:address location="..." /> and can't reach the service. This element is within the wsdl:port element which is found within wsdl:service element.